# Is it safe to assume that all nested RxJS Subscribe can be replaced by mergeMap?

Tags: rxjs, nested, subscribe

I got to refactor some code for a tremendous angular project I'm newly involved in. Some parts of the code lake of RxJS operators and do things like simple nested subscribes or copy/paste error handlers instead of using pipes.

Is it safe to assume that any simple 1 depth nested subscribes can be replaced by a mergeMap?

Let's take a `login` method like this :

```typescript
  private login() {
    this.userService.logIn(this.param1, this.param2).subscribe((loginResult: {}) => {
      this.userService.getInfo(this.param3).subscribe((user: UserModel) => { 
        // [the login logic]
      },
      (e) => {
        // [the error handling logic]
      })
    }, (e) => {
      // [The exact same copy/pasted error handling logic]
    });
  }
```

Is it safe to replace it with this?

```typescript
  private login() {
    this.userService.logIn(this.param1, this.param2)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((x) => this.userService.getInfo(this.param3))
    )
    .subscribe((user: UserModel) => { 
      // [the login logic that redirects to "my account" page]
    },
    (e) => {
      // [the error handling logic]
    });
  }
```

What would be the difference with flatMap or switchMap here, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

For your case I will go with SwitchMap.

mergeMap/FlatMap: transforms each emitted item to a new observable as defined by a function. Executes the executions in parallel and merges the results (aka flatMap) order doesn't matter.

swicthMap: transforms each emitted item to a new observable as defined by a function.

-Subscribers from prior inner observable.

-Subscribers to new inner observable.

-Inner observable are merged to the output stream.

-When you submit a new observable, multiple times the previous one gets cancelled and only emits the last one which is awesome for performance.